# radar chart with plotly (python 3x)

Tags: python, plotly, kaggle

I try to set up a radar chart with plotly but I currently have two issues:

- I have some spurious points that appear on the graph
- I don't manage to make the text of individual points appearing on hover

The whole script (with the graph) can be found on [this kaggle's page](https://www.kaggle.com/fabiendaniel/categorizing-actors-hands-on-plotly/).
The code I use to set up the radar chart is:

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
pyo.init_notebook_mode()
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import plotly.graph_objs as go


tr1 = (go.Scatter(r      = [6, 7],
                  t      = [120, 125],
                  mode   = 'markers',
                  name   = 'Drama',
                  text   = ['text_1', 'text_2'],
                  marker = dict(color = 'royalblue', size=110,
                                       line=dict(color='white'), opacity=0.7),
                  hoverinfo = 'all'
                  )) 
layout = go.Layout(
    title='Test Case',
    font=dict(
        size=15
    ),
    plot_bgcolor='rgb(223, 223, 223)',
    angularaxis=dict(        
        tickcolor='rgb(253,253,253)'
    ),
    hovermode='Closest',
)
fig = go.Figure(data = [tr1], layout=layout)
pyo.iplot(fig)
```

My main issue is that two points appear at coordinates: (t,r) = (3,12) and (4,13). Also, I want that 'text_1' and 'text_2' appear on hover but currently, only the points coordinates are shown.

Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

Finally, concerning the bad points, this is a [bug](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/2023) in plotly and for the labels, this is a [missing feature](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/94#issuecomment-330853403).